# Multiple Values per Single Checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a website which displays images from my database.

I echo the images using PHP and have a checkbox echoed below each image.

If the checkbox is ticked, and the form is submitted, the 'action' page will get the image name from the value of the checkbox - the value of the checkbox is the image name.

This is working great.

**My code is:**

I get my image name using...

```
$image_name = $fetch['image_name'];
```

I add the tick box and array below, as such...

(Don't forget, I am echoing all images from database so I need an array to determin which image is selected/ticked)

```
<input name="image[]" type="checkbox" value="'.$image_name.'" />
```

This gets the images name so I am able to echo the image name on the 'action' page.

**My problem is...**

I also need to have another checkbox (or 2) for image sizes (6x4, 7x5) etc.

I am unable to pass the 'value' of the size and the 'value' of the image name using a single checkbox!

Any ideas or advice?

Comment: Could you just concatenate the values and use that, like "imagename.jpg-100x200"?

Comment: Thanks for your response but unfortunately not, I need to add the image size selected into my database seperately

Comment: explode('-',$value) wouldn't work? A dash may not be the safest character to use (it might legitimately be in the filename), but the idea is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have ID of image You can do that:

```
<input name="image['.$imageID.']['6x4']" type="checkbox" value="'.$image_name.'" />
<input name="image['.$imageID.']['7x5']" type="checkbox" value="'.$image_name.'" />
```

On action side You will use foreach to get names and sizes.

Comment: Uh, just one more quick question, how would I 'foreach' the 2 arrays? I need to be able to input the image name into the database and the image size into the database...

Comment: foreach($_POST['image'] as $ImageID => $aArray) {
   foreach($aArray as $Size => $name) { ... }
}

Comment: Boogeroos...

I'm having trouble getting this to work! 

Could you do me a massive favor and answer the question with more example code, please!

I've got 2 checkboxes

<input name="image[][6x7]" type="checkbox" value="'.$image_name.'" /> 6x7

Etc...

I try send that through and get the value using...

foreach($_POST['image'] as $key => $name) {
 
foreach($name as $size => $size) {

}}

Help! Haha!

Comment: Here is an example [http://pastebin.com/h9ZXuZzf](http://pastebin.com/h9ZXuZzf) But I think that You should set the image keys -> <input name="image[**HERE**][6x7]" type="checkbox" value="'.$image_name.'" /> There should be images ID from database or something else like productId if this images is set to some product...

Comment: Boogeroos, I have followed your link and have got the script working perfectly!

Thank you so much for your time and help, truly appreciated!